# How to Generate Sine Wave With Specific Amplitude And Play Through IPython.display on Colab Python Notebook?

Tags: python, numpy, audio, google-colaboratory, ipython

I have the following code in my Colab Notebook to loop 1 second of a sine wave and one second of silence.
However, it just plays at full volume regardless what amplitude is set at.
How can I change my code so that it honors the amplitude?

```
from IPython.display import Audio, display
import numpy as np
duration = 1.0
frequency = 1000.0
amplitude = 0.5
sample_rate = 16000
time = np.arange(0, duration, 1/sample_rate)
data = amplitude * np.sin(2 * np.pi * frequency * time)
silence = np.zeros(sample_rate*1)
data = np.hstack((data, silence))
audio = Audio(data, rate=sr, autoplay=True)
audio.autoplay_attr = lambda: 'autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"'
display(audio)
```